# orderBy sum of related table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

If i have a post type **post** which hasMany **votes** that looks somehting like this:

```
post:   [id, title, content]
votes:  [my_vote, post_id, user_id]
```

where my_vote can be say -1, 0 or 1.

How do i list all posts ordered by the sum of my_vote? Can i do this in eloquent or do i have to use JOINS with fluent? Im looking to do something like

```
->orderBy(sum("votes-for-the-idea"))
```

Also i still need to access individual votes (specifically the votes of the current user).

Comment: Great question, I'm wondering this too.

Answer (score 0):

```
select post.*,
sum(votes.my_vote) as vote_num,
count(distinct votes.user_id) as user_vote_num
from post 
left join votes 
on post.id = votes.post_id 
group by post.id 
order by vote_num desc
```